# Enumerate with enumitem and \newcommand macro

Tags: macros, enumitem, optional-arguments

```
% !TeX spellcheck = he_IL
\documentclass[titlepage=false,12pt,titlepage]{scrreprt}

%\pagenumbering{roman}

\usepackage{ucs}   %  unicode support
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%-----
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{t1enc}

\usepackage[english,russian,hebrew]{babel}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}



\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{)\textrm{\arabic{enumi}}(}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\alph{enumii}(}


\setlist{topsep = 2 pt, partopsep = 1 pt, parsep = 0 pt, itemsep = 2 pt}



\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wasysym}




\newcommand{\mybigbox}{\APLbox}
\newcommand{\mybox}{\APLbox}
%------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\BoxArabicEnum}{)1( \APLbox}


\usepackage[left= 1cm, right= 1.5 cm, top=1cm,bottom=1 cm, footskip=0.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\L{First enumerate:}
\begin{enumerate}[ \BoxArabicEnum ]

\item  
a
\item
b
\item
c
\end{enumerate}

\L{Second enumerate:}

\begin{enumerate}[ )1( \APLbox ]

\item  
a
\item
b
\item
c
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

%----------------------------------

And here is the result:

[image: Result of compilation]

Questions:  Why "First enumerate:" is different from "Second enumerate:" and how to cause user-defined command `\BoxArabicEnum` to produce the same result as direct substitution  `)1( \APLbox` ?

Comment: I can't compile your example due to `hebrew`, but the main culprit is that `)1(` isn't recognized as a format inside of an macro when using `shortlabels` as an `enumitem`. Since that package is sophisticated, it's not necessary to screw up the `labelenumi` etc. macros with `\renewcommand` statements, just use `label=...`

Comment: Thank you, but this is not an answer, because I want to reproduce "\begin{enumerate}[ )1( \APLbox ]"  with help of command \BoxArabicEnum only in certain places.

Comment: It is an answer, but providing another solution ;-)

Comment: You can use the `label=` each time you want to have or define a special enumerate list using `newlist`

Comment: Sorry, but this is a bad solution, because in this case I should define several new enumerate lists.

Comment: Ok, your decision then -- You're using 1% of the features of `enumitem` only and complain about a 'bad solution' -- I leave it to others and we won't meet again.

Answer (score 2):

[`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) expects a key-value sequence and therefore doesn't expand the optional argument that is supplied. If you're sold on using this interface, you need to make sure that `enumitem` receives an expanded version of what you supply.

Below I've redefined `enumerate` to expands its optional argument. I've also opted to use a different way of printing `\APLbox` using an `\fbox` with invisible horizontal and vertical struts (zero-width `\rule`s):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\textrm{\arabic{enumi}})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\alph{enumii})}

\usepackage{wasysym,letltxmacro}

\newcommand{\mybigbox}{\APLbox}
\newcommand{\mybox}{\APLbox}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\BoxArabicEnum}{(1) \protect\fbox{\protect\rule{.55em}{0pt}\protect\rule{0pt}{.7em}}}
%\renewcommand{\BoxArabicEnum}{(1) \protect\APLbox}

\LetLtxMacro\oldenumerate\enumerate
\let\endoldenumerate\endenumerate
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{enumerate}[1][]
  {\begingroup\protected@edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\begin{oldenumerate}[#1]}\x}
  {\end{oldenumerate}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

First enumerate:
\begin{enumerate}[ \BoxArabicEnum ]
  \item a
  \item b
  \item c
\end{enumerate}

Second enumerate:
\begin{enumerate}[ (1) \APLbox ]
  \item a
  \item b
  \item c
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```